# Vega in Heston / Bates Model

Tags: heston, vega, bates

Just a question regarding "convention": Is the Vega in Heston / Bates model the sensitivity with regards to $\sqrt v_0$ or a term of $\sqrt v_0$ and $\theta$ (Long term variance)?

Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $v_0$ and $\theta$ are responsible for the initial and long-term level of the variance,[Zhu (2010)](http://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783642018077) recommends basing vega on those two parameters. Both parameters represent variance, so to create measures of sensitivity to volatility, Zhu (2010) defines two vegas, one based on $\upsilon=\sqrt v_0$ and the other based on $\omega=\sqrt \theta$ for the call are, therefore, the derivatives
\begin{align}
\vartheta_1=\frac{\partial C}{\partial\upsilon}=\frac{\partial C}{\partial v_0}2\sqrt v_0
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
\vartheta_2=\frac{\partial C}{\partial\omega}=\frac{\partial C}{\partial \theta}2\sqrt \theta
\end{align}
The first vega is
\begin{align}
\vartheta_1=S\,e^{-q\tau}\frac{\partial P_1}{\partial v_0}2\sqrt{v_0}-K\,e^{-r\tau}\frac{\partial P_2}{\partial v_0}2\sqrt{v_0}
\end{align}
where, for $j=1,2$
\begin{align}
P_j=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}Re\left[\frac{e^{-i\phi\ln K}f_j(x_t,v_t,t;\phi)D_j(\tau;\phi)}{i\phi}\right]d\phi
\end{align}
such that $x_t=\ln S_t$ and
\begin{align}
&\\
&f_j(x_t,v_t,t;\phi)=exp[C_j(\tau;\phi)+D_j(\tau;\phi)v_t+i\phi x_t]\\
&\\
&D_j(\tau;\phi)=\frac{b_j-\rho\sigma i\phi+d_j}{\sigma^2}\left(\frac{1-e^{d_j\tau}}{1-g_j e^{d_j\tau}}\right)\\
&\\
&C_j(\tau;\phi)=r i\phi\tau+\frac{\kappa\theta}{\sigma^2}\left[(b_j-\rho\sigma i\phi+d_j)\left(\frac{1-g_{j}\,e^{d_j\tau}}{1- g_j}\right)\right]\\
\end{align}
where

\begin{align}
&d_j=\sqrt{(\rho\sigma i\phi-b_j)^2-\sigma^2(2\,u_{j}\,i\phi-\phi^2)}\\
&g_j=\frac{b_j-\rho\sigma i\phi+d_j}{b_j-\rho\sigma i\phi-d_j}\\
&b_1=\kappa+\lambda-\rho\sigma,b_2=\kappa+\lambda,u_1=-\frac{1}{2},u_2=\frac{1}{2}
\end{align}
for more details look at [this](http://elis.sigmath.es.osaka-u.ac.jp/research/Heston-original.pdf)